# Replace Placeholders in Html with Model Object

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a hard time explaining what I'm exactly trying to do. There's probably a name for it, but I don't know what it is.
First, I have a model such as:

```
   public class Customer
   {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public int ProductId { get; set; }
     ...more properties...

     public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
   }
   public class Product
   {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Description { get; set; }
     ...more properties...

   }
```

Second, I have a string of HTML text with placeholders in `{}`. I'd like to have something like `{Id}` and have it replace the Html text with the model properties.

> <div><span>Name</span><span>{Id}-{Product.Name}</span></div>

My thought was to use a NameValueCollection to get the Model properties as strings. Using reflection, I can do that for the base properties, but not for something like `Product.Name`.

Am I going about this the wrong way? What could I use to get a NameValueCollection that I could loop through and do a replace of the Html?

Here is the current code I have (skips virtual properties):

```
public virtual NameValueCollection GetNameValueCollection(Object obj)
{
  Type type = obj.GetType();
  PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();
  var coll = new NameValueCollection();
  foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
  {
    if(!property.GetGetMethod().IsVirtual)
    {
      if (property.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime))
      {
        var date = (DateTime)property.GetValue(obj, null);
        coll.Add(property.Name, date.ToLongDateString());
      }
      else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime?))
      {
        var date = (DateTime?)property.GetValue(obj, null);
        if (date.HasValue)
        {
          coll.Add(property.Name, date.Value.ToLongDateString());
        }
        else
        {
          coll.Add(property.Name, string.Empty);
        }
      }
      else
      {
        var value = property.GetValue(obj, null);
        if (value != null)
        {
          coll.Add(property.Name, value.ToString());
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return coll;
}
```

This should be recursive, but it seems like there should be a better way. By the way, I don't need a `NameValueCollection` specifically (could be `Dictionary<string,string>` for example). Thoughts? Is there a nuget package that already does this?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just using what I had and added a sub section for handling child objects. I didn't want to do full recursion since I only wanted the direct child objects, not all the way through the chain.